# How to define a graphic

Tags: diagrams

I'm new in LaTex. I need to draw a graphic like the image and each rectangles of image must have the size shown in Figure. I drwan it by MS power point but I need to do by LaTex. Can you help me? Thank you in advance for your help and collaboration! [image]
Thank you in advance for your help and collaboration!

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far and where your problem is? Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.