# How to generate this image?

Tags: graphics

I'm new in LaTex. I need to draw a graphic like the image and each rectangles of image must have the size shown in Figure. I drawn it by MS power point but I need to do by LaTex. Can you help me? Or how to start?[image]
Thank you in advance for your help and collaboration!

Now I'm able to generate the box by this code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata} % LATEX and plain TEX
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds, chains,positioning,fit,petri,matrix,shapes.arrows,shadows,backgrounds}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}



\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,shadings,graphs}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners, thick,node distance=7em, text width=6em, text centered , inimum height=3.5em}}
\tikzset{container/.style={draw, rectangle , dashed, inner sep=2em}}
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -latex '}}


%Disegno per i grafici TikZ
\definecolor{bluei}{RGB}{83,116,191}
\definecolor{blueii}{RGB}{207,212,232}
\definecolor{greeni}{RGB}{135,200,81}
\definecolor{greenii}{RGB}{216,235,207}

\tikzset{
  myiblock/.style 2 args={
    draw=white,
    fill=#1,
    line width=1pt,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=1cm,
    align=center,
    text=white,
    font=\sffamily,
    text width=#2
  },
  myoblock/.style={
    fill=#1,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    inner xsep=10pt
  }
}

\begin{document}


%1chain

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3pt and 1cm]
\node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm}]
  (info1)
  {Id1 long 7 chars};
\node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info1]
  (info2)
  {Id2 long 7 chars};
 \node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info2]
  (info3)
  {Id3 long 7 chars};
  \node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info3]
  (info4)
  {Id4 long 7 chars};
    \node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info4]
  (info5)
  {Id5 long 7 chars};
    \node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info5]
  (info6)
  {Id6 long 7 chars};
    \node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info6]
  (info7)
  {Id7 long 7 chars};


\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}

\end{pgfonlayer}

%2 chain

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,node distance=3pt and 1cm]
\node[myiblock={greeni}{4cm}]
  (infoob1)
  {Text1 long 34 chars};
\node[myiblock={greeni}{4cm},below=of infoob1]
  (infoob2)
  {Text2 long 34 chars};
\node[myiblock={greeni}{4cm},below=of infoob2]
  (infoob3)
  {Text3 long 34 chars};
 \node[myiblock={greeni}{4cm},below=of infoob3]
  (infoob4)
  {Text4 long 34 chars};
  \node[myiblock={greeni}{4cm},below=of infoob4]
  (infoob5)
  {Text5 long 34 chars};
  \node[myiblock={greeni}{4cm},below=of infoob5]
  (infoob6)
  {Text6 long 34 chars};
  \node[myiblock={greeni}{4cm},below=of infoob6]
  (infoob7)
  {Text7 long 34 chars};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

%3 chain

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3pt and 1cm]
\node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm}]
  (info1)
  {Label1 long 20 chars};
\node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info1]
  (info2)
  {Label2 long 20 chars};
 \node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info2]
  (info3)
  {Label3 long 20 chars};
  \node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info3]
  (info4)
  {Label4 long 20 chars};
    \node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info4]
  (info5)
  {Label5 long 20 chars};
    \node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info5]
  (info6)
  {Label6 long 20 chars};
    \node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info6]
  (info7)
  {Label7 long 20 chars};


\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}

\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

question:
1. how i can add the other box
2. how to add the ...between the box (see the first chain)
3. how to keep the same box size of the original image?

Thanks Marta

Comment: Asking the same question twice and not giving more information is not really helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280563/how-to-define-a-graphic

Comment: Marta, for starting draw your image please see similar solution provided as answer in this community as well to look in http://www.texample.net/. To read TikZ manual also will be helpful. If you more prefer instead TikZ/PGF to use ps-trick, google for it (I don't use it, however here are active some good experts for it). For start try to show, what you do so far.

Comment: Marta, please ask new question in which you put your MWE (from question above) and add what it  generate and what you like to obtain. Based on your example I prepare an answer, however I cant upload it.